# Finding top 3 feature importance using Ensemble Voting Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, ensemble-learning

I have a classification problem where I have to find the top 3 features 
using  VOTING CLASSIFIER method having PCA, xgboost, RANDOM FOREST, 
LOGISTIC REG AND DECISION TREE in it.

I am a beginner and I don't know how to use the Voting classifier for getting feature importance.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression  
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier  
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier  
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA  
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier   

log_clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=2)

rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier
(n_estimators=150, max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=6, 
max_features=0.3, n_jobs=-1, random_state=2)

gbm_clf= GradientBoostingClassifier 
(n_estimators=150, max_depth=3, min_samples_leaf=3, max_features=0.3, 
learning_rate=0.05, subsample=0.4,random_state=2)`

estimators = [('lr', log_clf), ('rf', rnd_clf), ('gbm', gbm_clf)]

voting_clf = VotingClassifier(estimators=estimators,voting='hard')

voting_clf.fit(train.drop(['target'],1),train['target'])
```

Exceptation: It should give me feature importance of the variables using voting classifier having pca,xgboost,dt,rf and lr.

Comment: I don't understand how you are using PCA. You have imported this in your sample code above but not used it anywhere. Also PCA is a method of dimensional reduction, not a classification algorithm.

Comment: yeah, because i dint know how to use pca in voting classifier. Even i was confused when i got this problem. So, i was just searching for any way around.

Comment: One possibility is to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality to 3 before using the other classifiers, e.g. see the user guide here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html

But that's not really what you've asked for. Is this a homework problem? Can you give us any more details of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the underlying classifiers from your `voting_clf` object and extract the feature importance of these.
For example:

```
for alg in voting_clf.named_estimators:
    clf = voting_clf.named_estimators[alg]
    # extract feature importance for clf
    # Note different algorithms have different 
    # methods for feature importance
```

Since you are ensembling algorithms with fundamentally different concepts of 'feature importance' I do not think there is a well defined way of deciding which features are most important in the ensembled result.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem, however, Robert King's approach doesn't work, since VotingRegressor (I'm working with regression) has several fields with estimators and in the field *named_estimators* they're not fitted, so the feature importance extraction couldn't be done. You can see how one of the named estimators looks like in the second pic.

[image]

[image]

The proper field with fitted estimators is *named_estimators_* and it looks like:
[image]

And the code to get all importances

```
    def __get_feature_importances(self, train_columns):
    feature_imp = dict()
    for est in self.model.estimators_:
        if type(est) == catboost.core.CatBoostRegressor:
            feature_imp['catboost'] = dict(zip(train_columns, est.feature_importances_))
        elif type(est) == lightgbm.sklearn.LGBMRegressor:
            feature_imp['lgbm'] = dict(zip(train_columns, est.feature_importances_))
        elif type(est) == xgboost.sklearn.XGBRegressor:
            feature_imp['xgboost'] = dict(zip(train_columns, est.feature_importances_))
    return feature_imp
```

We have to compare them by types, since *named_estimators_* don't have names.